# Does changing character varying length have an impact on Postgresql query performance?

Tags: postgresql

Does it make a query faster when a Postgresql column is set as `character varying (50)` instead of `character varying (255)` ?

Comment: No, why would you assume it does? It only cuts down the storable data.

Comment: What Bergi said. Additionally: the "magic number" 255 has no implied optimizations. Using 257 would have the same performance and storage costs (apart from allowing two more characters)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your answer. If I have a column where the max possible length for an entry is 50, I'd better set it to varchar(255) or is there a better choice which may improve performances ?

Comment: @DevonDahon If you want a max possible length of 50, it needs to be `varchar(50)`. This has nothing to do with performance.